# Sorting Lists in a lexicographical way using priority queues

Tags: python, linked-list, priority-queue

I have been trying to sort a group of lists in a lexicographical way using priority queues which are constructed using linked lists.
the priorities are the elements of the lists
for example:

```
A=[1,70,60]
B=[0,100,100]
C=[1,70,70]
D=[1,80,30]
```

suppose that A,B,C,D are four college students applying for a job, and suppose that the first element represents the student's attitude, the second element represents the student's grade on his final exam, and the last element is the student's mid term exam grade.

so the correct order to interview these students is D>C>A>B (D first and B last)

after numerous tries, the code seems to give the correct order for elements of the queue. but if you miss with the values of the lists, it will not give the correct order anymore
for example: changing B to B=Student('B',1,100,100) should get B to the top of the queue, but it's not doing this.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,name,att,fin,mid):
        self.name=name
        self.att=att
        self.fin=fin
        self.mid=mid
        self.next=None
class Student:
    def __init__(self,name,att,fin,mid):
        self.name=name
        self.att=att
        self.fin=fin
        self.mid=mid
class PQ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None
        self.size=0
        
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head==None
        
    def enqueue(self,student):
        node=Node(student.name,student.att,student.fin,student.mid)
        if (self.isEmpty()): 
            self.head=node
            self.tail=node
        else: 
            if(node.att<=self.head.att):
                node.next=self.head
                self.head=node
            else:
                current=self.head
                prev=current
                while(current!=None and  current.att < node.att ):
                    prev=current
                    current=current.next
                while(current!=None and  current.fin < node.fin ):
                    prev=current
                    current=current.next
                while(current!=None and  current.mid < node.mid ):
                    prev=current
                    current=current.next
                prev.next=node
                node.next=current

    def peek(self):
        print(self.head.name)
        print(self.head.next.name)
        print(self.head.next.next.name)
        print(self.head.next.next.next.name)
        
A=Student('A',1,70,60)
B=Student('B'0,100,100)
C=Student('C',1,70,70)
D=Student('D',1,80,30)

pq1=PQ()
pq1.enqueue(A)
pq1.enqueue(B)
pq1.enqueue(C)
pq1.enqueue(D)
pq1.peek()
```

I know that it can be done in other ways but these are the concepts that I am trying to learn.

any one has any idea of how can I do this using the priority queues?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the second `while` loop you should not continue the loop when `current.att` is no longer the same as `node.att`. That while loop is intended to break a tie when those are the same.

For similar reasons the third loop should only continue when both the `att` and `fin` attributes are the same for `current` and `node`.

Some other issues:

- You should increment `self.size` when enqueuing a node
- `self.tail` should be updated when the node happens to get inserted as last node

It is a pity that you have this code repetition, only to compare three-part keys. If you would put those three key values in a tuple, then you can just compare the tuples, without having to deal with this complexity of breaking ties. So that means in `Node` you would have a `data` attribute that is a tuple of `att`,`fin`,`mid` and `name`. To keep the access to those *names*, I would suggest using a *named* tuple for this purpose:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Data = namedtuple("Data", "att, fin, mid, name")

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, att, fin, mid):
        self.data = Data(att, fin, mid, name)
        self.next = None
        
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, att, fin, mid):
        self.name = name
        self.att = att
        self.fin = fin
        self.mid = mid

class PQ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0
        
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def nodes(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next
        
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from (node.data.name for node in self.nodes())

    def enqueue(self, student):
        self.size += 1
        node = Node(student.name, student.att, student.fin, student.mid)
        if self.isEmpty(): 
            self.head = self.tail = node
        elif node.data <= self.head.data:
            node.next = self.head
            self.head = node
        else:
            prev = next(prev for prev in self.nodes() 
                        if not prev.next or node.data <= prev.next.data)
            node.next = prev.next
            prev.next = node
            if not node.next:
                self.tail = node
            
        
A = Student('A', 1, 70, 60)
B = Student('B', 0, 100, 100)
C = Student('C', 1, 70, 70)
D = Student('D', 1, 80, 30)

pq1 = PQ()
pq1.enqueue(A)
pq1.enqueue(B)
pq1.enqueue(C)
pq1.enqueue(D)
print(*pq1)
```

Comment: thanks @trincot . I took use of your first notes regarding the while loops and I fixed my code. as for the solution you presented, I think it's a bit heavy for me right now as I'm still new to OOP in general.